# Show that the set of all closed points is dense in $\operatorname{Spec}A(X)$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Let $R = A(X)$ be the coordinate ring of an affine variety $X$ over an algebraically closed field. Show that the set of all closed points is dense in $\operatorname{Spec}R$ (which means by definition that every non-empty open subset of $\operatorname{Spec}R$ contains a closed point).

I think it suffices to show that for any $f \in R$ the distinguished open set $D(f)$ contains a closed point.

So let $f \in R$ and consider $D(f) = \{ \mathfrak{p} \mid f \notin \mathfrak{p}\}$. To show that this contains a closed point we need to find $\mathfrak{p} \in D(f)$ such that $\overline{\{\mathfrak{p}\}} = \{\mathfrak{p}\}$. I'm a little confused with this as $$\overline{\{\mathfrak{p}\}} = \{\mathfrak{p}\}$$ is equivalent with $\mathfrak{p}$ being maximal, but I don't know why $D(f)$ needs to contain a maximal ideal?

Comment: Do you know a standard argument for showing that maximal ideals satisfying some condition or other exist?

Comment: Using Zorn's lemma? @ZhenLin

Comment: In other words, you want to show that unless $D(f)$ is empty (what does that mean for $f$?), $f$ cannot belong to all maximal ideals of $R$. So one possible way to do this is to find out what the intersection of all maximal ideals of $R$ is. It is called its Jacobson radical, if that helps.

Comment: So I guess we can't just state that $D(f)$ contains a maximal ideal due to Zorn's lemma @CaptainLama

Comment: You need to justify it with an actual argument! Yes, use Zorn’s lemma, but how?

Comment: Well $D(f)$ consists of prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}$ such that $f \notin \mathfrak{p}$. Order these by inclusion and use it? @ZhenLin

Comment: Sure, but how do you know that poset is chain complete, and how do you know what you get is actually a maximal ideal in the usual sense of the word? Don't just guess, prove it!

Comment: I managed to do this via contradiction. Suppose that $D(f)$ doesn't contain any maximal ideals. Then $f \in M$ for every maximal ideal $M$ of $R$. Thus $f \in J(R)$ where $J(R)$ is the Jacobson radical. In our case $J(R) = \sqrt{(0)}$ so $f \in \sqrt{(0)}$ i.e. $f$ is nilpotent and $D(f)$ must be empty. @ZhenLin